# how to use Apexchart js in vaadin

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, apexcharts

I am using vaadin 24 with springboot, I am searching for a way to use it in my project, the dataseries is comming from database, so I need to read data dynamically, I don't know from where should I start, I made a search already, but non of the results are worked
I have the following html and js code, i want to use it in my project as a component

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ApexCharts Example</title>

    <!-- Include ApexCharts CSS file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="apexcharts.min.css">
    <!-- Include Bootstrap CSS (optional, for styling) -->
</head>
<body>

        <!-- Container for the chart -->
        <div id="chart"></div>

    <!-- Include ApexCharts JS file -->
    <script src="apexcharts.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Your custom script for creating and updating the chart -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

````
    series: [44, 55, 13, 43, 22],
    chart: {
    width: 380,
    type: 'pie',
  },
  labels: ['Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C', 'Team D', 'Team E'],
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 480,
    options: {
      chart: {
        width: 200
      },
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
      }
    }
  }]
  };

  var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
  chart.render();```
Also, i want to pass data from my java class, not being static like this, any help ?
````

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Use vaadin addon [https://vaadin.com/directory/component/apexchartsjs](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/apexchartsjs)